# MEF ExportFactory does not dispose of IDisposable ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, dispose, idisposable

I'm using MEF as the IoC container in WPF with Caliburn.Micro framework. The MEF container resides in the `Bootstrapper`. `Bootstrapper` has the method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{            
   DisplayRootViewFor<ViewModels.Main.MainViewModel>();
}
```

Now, the `MainViewModel` has this:

```
private IEnumerable<ExportFactory<Screen>> _screenList { get; set; }        

[ImportingConstructor]
public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, [ImportMany] IEnumerable<ExportFactory<Screen>> screenList)
{
    _screenList = screenList;
    eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);        
}
```

The class basically has an `IEnumerable` of `ExportFactory`. A `Screen` is basically a `ViewModel` that inherits from `VMBase` which in turn inherits from `Screen`. Now, some of those `ViewModel` use a Unit of Work, which, in turn, has a `DbContext` injected into it via the `constructor`.

So basically, the dependency chain is like this:
`DbContext -> UnitOfWork (IDisposable) -> ViewModelBase(IDisposable) -> ViewModels`. These `ViewModel` are instantiated using the `ExportFactory` in the `MainViewModel`.

The `MainViewModel` is subscribed to the `eventAggregator`, and  `Handler` of `MainViewModel` calls the `ExportFactory` to create a new instance of a `ViewModel` as necessary. The problem is, when that `ViewModel` is closed, the `DbContext` is not properly disposed of.

This is the `Handle` method:

```
public void Handle(Type message)
{            
   DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true);           
   ActivateItem(screenList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CreateExport().Value.GetType() == message).CreateExport().Value);           
}
```

This creates new instances of `DbContext`, but doesn't call `Dispose()` of `ViewModelBase` ever, as I verified using breakpoints.

I tried changing the `Handle` method to call `Dispose()` like this:

```
DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true);
_currentLifetimeContext?.Dispose();
_currentLifetimeContext = _screenList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CreateExport().Value.GetType() == message).CreateExport();
ActivateItem(_currentLifetimeContext.Value);
```

but it throws an error "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

How can I properly dispose of the `DbContext` in my application?

Comment: I can add more details about the project, if need be.

Comment: _"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."_ So, the DbContext has then been properly disposed already. I am confused. Your question revolves around you assuming that the DbContext is not being disposed, albeit the error message is saying to you in no uncertain terms that it actually is...

Comment: When I change the `Handle` as already mentioned, then it works, but it can't create a new instance of a `ViewModel` anymore.

Comment: Are you aware that with this statement `_screenList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CreateExport().Value.GetType() == message).CreateExport()` you are creating in worst case N + 1 view-models (where `N == screenList.Count()`) and two of those view-models will be of the same type; and additionally this could throw a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @dymanoid Is there any way to improve the worst case performance?

Comment: Don't forget about creation policy. Use appropriate attributes for [export and import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.creationpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: I am using `PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)` for all of them.

Comment: The problem is that, when the `DbContext` is properly disposed once, the `ExportFactory` cannot create a `ViewModel` that gets a `DbContext` injected through the constructor. It cannot create another instance of `DbContext`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost impossible to state why your code is failing without testing it in its entirety. However, in my limited experience with MEF, I have found that most of the disposal problems are created when the exports are not explicitly marked to be `NonShared`. This is one of the annoyances of MEF, where it treats all components to be singleton by default. My advice is to explicitly mark each and every export of yours to be `NonShared`, unless you want a singleton. Not just the `ViewModels`. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly the problem. I was using `PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)` for all `viewmodel` as well as the `DbContext`, but not the `Unit of Work`. This was the solution.